# MySQL: How to use column alias in left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use column alias in the left join but I get sql error with uknown field.

```
select *, (select SenderId from messages where messageId = 5) as senderId  from threads 
Left join users where users.id = senderId
```

This query is quite simple but why is not it working or what is the best way to achieve this ?

I'll really appreciate any contribution.
Thanks

Comment: Your query has no from clause, and if you refer to the field it should be senderId.SenderId

Comment: sorry just fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use column aliases in `ON` or `WHERE` clauses, because column aliases are assigned to values in the result set, but `ON` and `WHERE` are used to create the result set. You need to use another `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t.*, m.senderId, u.*
FROM threads AS t
CROSS JOIN messages AS m
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.SenderId
WHERE m.messageId = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for response. 
But unfortunately your query produced sql error 
Unrecognized keyword. (near "CROSS" at position 1155)

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Are you sure you're using MySQL, not some other database?

Comment: Yes i am sure I am using MySQL

Comment: Unrecognized keyword. (near "CROSS" at position 1155)

Comment: That error message is coming from phpMyAdmin, not MySQL itself. I'm not sure why it doesn't recognize the keyword

Comment: Try removing `CROSS`. MySQL treats a `JOIN` that has no `ON` clause as a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*, mu.* 
 from threads as t
 Left Join
           (select SenderId,users. *  
            from messages, users  
            where messages.messageId 
            =  users.id and messsageId = 5) as mu
```

You need to join threads and mu tables with some id